# Pagination stream in the soundcloud?

Tags: pagination, soundcloud

Please tell me how to do pagination in soundcloud stream? Using developers.soundcloud.com I do not understand. loading content is cut off after 27 days. I need to see more than 3 months. Before there was a refresh button at the end of the stream by clicking on the button, the loading continued. I need easy navigation through the stream, maybe somebody exercised some methods? Help please, I would be very grateful.

Comment: you know how SO works? please share code and what you have tried, we are not here for brainstorming. btw, afaik the endpoints you are talking about are not public, you mean when you logon your artist stream, right?

Comment: yeah, I don't even know how I can register my app. How can I make my stream in the form of pages, but not the scroll. I need a detailed plan of action. I badly understand in the API. Please help.

Comment: here are the docs for that: https://developers.soundcloud.com - there you can register your app. regarding the endpoint for the stream, afaik its not public, therefore I'd say you need to use user or tracks endpoint of the people you follow. i guess thats a good starting point.

Comment: pagination is nicely described here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated